# API requests with axios always unauthorized with Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api, axios

I'm working on a personal project using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) 5.6 and [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library (standard Laravel [5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) package).

I need to send first GET then POST request using Laravel's API and axios' http requests, but I'm not using Passport or any library like that since it's an internal API serving only VueJS to obtain stuff from the database.

If I set my API routes using `auth:api` middleware, I always get unauthorized response, whichever is the request type, this is the error output :

> Error: Request failed with status code 401

The message :

```
message: "Unauthenticated."
```

But, as I read in the documentation, axios headers are set inside laravel's `bootstrap.js` to read the authorization token from meta tags (and the code is there) :

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

// further down the file...
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

While, if needed, here's the http request code :

```
axios.post('/api/latest', formData)
```

So, why am I unauthenticated if those are set?

I've tried removing the `auth:api` middleware and, of course, it's working:

```
- Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/latest', 'InternalApiController@latestEp');
+ Route::get('/latest', 'InternalApiController@latestEp');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I'm not using Passort or any library like that since it's an internal API serving only VueJS to obtain stuff from the database.

If the API is not stateless, meaning that the user is known to be logged in with a standard session cookie, then you can just use the default `'web'` middleware for the API routes.

In the default `RouteServiceProvider`, change the `mapApiRoutes` function to use the `web` middleware instead:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        // ->middleware('api')
        ->middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

---

That being said, you should really put the API routes behind the default `'auth'` middleware since they're not throttled by default.

In the `routes/api.php` file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/latest', 'InternalApiController@latest');
});
```

And if you want to ensure it's an AJAX request, you can create a simple middleware that checks that the request has the `X-Requested-With` header set to `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
class RequestIsAjax
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->ajax()) {
            return redirect()->route('login.index');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And register it within the `$routeMiddleware` array inside the `\App\Http\Kernel` class.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'ajax' => \App\Http\Middleware\RequestIsAjax::class,
```

Comment: Even changing that, if I put in my api.php `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/latest', 'InternalApiController@latest');` I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @K3nzie you're still using `auth:api` which check for the `api` auth guard. Just use `middleware('auth')` and it will work.

Comment: ok fixed it, but still,this way the api endpoint is accessible from the web while only want it to be used from Vue, is that possible?

Comment: @K3nzie Vue is within the browser, so it doesn't matter, it needs to be accessible. The thing you can do to avoid abuse is make sure that each API route needs authentication and that CORS is disable on this server so only calls from your own website will work.

Comment: besides CORS which is server config, how could I create another authentication so that the route isn't accessible by browser URL? Should I just go for a custom middleware?

Comment: @K3nzie I added a simple AJAX check middleware which would help hide the API endpoints from an accidental browser navigation.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been very helpful :)

Comment: Works like charm! You saved me

Comment: It's working when i Changed "->middleware('api')" to ->middleware('web') but the question is, is this a good solution?

Comment: @1247p I cover the risks in my answer. You should put your API behind the `auth` middleware at least, and add throttling if needed.

Answer (score 3):

With Laravel 8, I was getting a 401 error when trying to request something from the backend api. Following the accepted answer got me close, but it still didn't work. I believe this was because I have the dashboard on a subdomain as `users.mydomain.tld` and where I was using Axios was on the primary domain as `mydomain.tld/some/path`. The issue is the path for the session cookies. When re-configuring this, you need to clear all the cookies (dev toolbar). Then re-login like normal after you have made your changes. Else, the cookies will be messed up and you won't see it fixed or you wont be able to login at all until you clear them.

I reverted all the changes I made (following the accepted answer) and pinned down the `SESSION_DOMAIN` environment variable being the key ingredient, at least when it comes to the main user's area being on a sub-domain.

In your `.env` file:

```php
SESSION_DOMAIN=".yourdomain.tld"
```

In `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` change `api` to `web` in the `boot()` method:

```php
Route::prefix('api')
    //->middleware('api')
    ->middleware('web')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

In `routes/api.php`:

```php
Route::middleware('auth')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

In your `resources/js/bootstrap.js`:

```php
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

After modifying the `bootstrap.js` file, you will need to run `npm run dev` again to recompile.

---

Now, you should be able to use Axios in your frontend JavaScript. Whether it be jQuery or Vue, whatever you are using.

```js
axios.get('/api/user')
    .then(response => console.dir(response.data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I'm more suprised my question from 3 years ago still gets attention haha but good to know! useful information

Answer (score 0):

CSRF-token is not the same as an authorization token. Most likely you will manually need to add the authorization token, which is probably like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization), depending on your method of authorization.